# Is there an isomorphism between $\{\frac{m}{2^n}:m,n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } m < n\}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The middle thirds removed in the formation of the cantor set have a natural ordering. I'm trying to show that we can find an isomorphism between these and the rational numbers with the usual ordering.

Each removed middle third can be identified by it's center point: 1/2, 1/4, 3/4, 1/8, 3/8, 5/8, 7/8,... and the order defined on the middle thirds is just the "$<$" ordering.

So what I need to do is show that the set $\{\frac{m}{2^n}:m,n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } m < n\}$ with the $<$ ordering is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ with the $<$ ordering.

Comment: Cantor characterized $\mathbb Q$: Any countable linear order that is dense in itself and has no first or last element is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$. The proof uses the back-and-forth technique to build the isomorphism recursively by stages. It is easy to see that the set you describe satisfies this characterization.